# I am deploying laravel project on heroku, but when I write "git push heroku master" it shows "ERROR: Dependency installation failed!""

Tags: laravel, github, heroku

I could not deploy laravel project to Heroku
First when I wrote "Heroku open" it showed "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server." Then I added to scripts part of composer.json

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "chmod -R 775 public/"
        ]
```

Then it shows this ERROR

Error

```
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-install-cmd script terminated with an error
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - A post-install-cmd script terminated with an error
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to frozen-harbor-81797.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-harbor-81797.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozen-harbor-81797.git'
```

Comment: Please add some more details like PHP version , buildpack and laravel version.if you are using public repo then please share the url

Comment: https://github.com/TolibRakhmonov/Antifreez url for github repository

Comment: Laravel version: 5.8.18